# How can I add 2 different versions of OpenZeppelin in a Foundry project

Tags: foundry

Currently going through Ethernaut, it involves contracts with different Solidity versions that import OpenZeppelin contracts.

To add Openzeppelin lib in foundry:

`forge install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts` will install the latest version.

To add Openzeppelin lib with Solidity 0.6, in releases, it says to use `v3.4.0`, so in foundry:

`forge install OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@v3.4.0`

The problem is that it replaces my current OpenZeppelin installation. How can I have both v3.4.0 and the latest (v4.8.1).

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have two different submodules depending on git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35978137/3873510).

Comment: I think the solution I found is related

Answer (score 2):

I just found out how to do so following [these instructions](https://github.com/foundry-rs/foundry/issues/1391#issuecomment-1107127594):

To add the good version into another name, type:

`forge install openzeppelin-contracts-06=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@v3.4.0`

And add into `remappings.txt` :

`openzeppelin-contracts-06/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts-06`